# Testing Graphene returns error JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

I am new to Unit Test on Graphene and DJango. I am trying to test my graphql query by graphene https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/testing/
But I have no idear why I am getting this error. Please help me.

import json
from graphene_django.utils.testing import GraphQLTestCase

```
# Create your tests here.
class CryptoBankQueryTestCase(GraphQLTestCase):
    def test_cryptobank_query(self):
        response = self.query(
            '''
            query cryptoBank($id: Int!){
                cryptoBank(cryptoBankId: $id) {
                    id,
                    name,
                    phoneNumber,
                    address
                }
            }
            ''',
            op_name="cryptoBank",
            variables={"cryptoBankId": 1}
        )

        content = json.loads(response.content)
        
        # This validates the status code and if you get errors
        self.assertResponseNoErrors(response)

        # Add some more asserts if you like
```

## Error:

```
ERROR: test_cryptobank_query (cryptobank.tests.test_cryptobank_query.CryptoBankQueryTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cafafanscoders/Desktop/python/CryptoBankGraphQL/src/cryptobank/tests/test_cryptobank_query.py", line 22, in test_cryptobank_query
    content = json.loads(response.content)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Comment: does your view has an authentication?

Comment: Yes, but nothing is wrong with my authentication; the problem is from the unit test

Comment: it seems the test client is not logged-in and hence client has got some other ***HTML*** page and which is not JSON response.

Comment: The error occurs on the `json.loads()` so it looks like it's a json issue but in fact, the response object already contains an error. I'd suggest to add a `        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)` to make the issue less misleading.